# How do I hook a pytest plugin into a unittest-based class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-asyncio

My problem: I need a simple way to mark test methods as coroutines.
(Among other reasons, I want to minimize the diff between the asyncio version and the original code.)

The following code works – except for `test_one`, which is ignored.

I've looked at the internals of `pytest` and `pytest-asyncio`, and while I (mostly) understand how it hooks itself up to augment simple test functions, I can't figure out how do do the same thing with unittest methods.

So how do I do that?

```
import unittest
import asyncio
import pytest

class TestSimple(unittest.TestCase):

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    def test_one(self):
        print("One")
        yield from asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        print("Two")

    def test_two(self):
        print("Three")

def test_three():
    print("Four")

@pytest.mark.asyncio
def test_four():
    print("Five")
    yield from asyncio.sleep(0.2)
    print("Six")
```

Answer (score 0):

Interleaving unittest style with native pytest is not possible.

If you need to write unittest-style test you may use decorator like e.g. [aioredis](https://github.com/aio-libs/aioredis/blob/master/tests/connection_test.py#L11) does.